# Changing values with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to solve a problem, where I can change owner over a given account. My problem is that it disregards the account number and changes user2 to user1 on all cases nevermind account number.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE change_owner (
IN fr_user_id int,
IN to_user_id int,
IN p_account_id int)
BEGIN
start transaction;

UPDATE accountowner SET user_id = to_user_id WHERE account_id = p_account_id; 

commit;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

What happens when I call this procedure,

call change_owner('1','2','3');

is that it will change all the owners with id '1' to id '2', it does not take into account that I only want this change at account '3'.

I.e. The user with id '2' takes over all the accounts that user with id '1' used to own.

I suspect that I am missing some kind of condition but I could not figure it out yet after maaaany long hours. -.-"

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Your code should do what you want.

Comment: ….WHERE account_id = p_account_id and user_id = fr_user_id; Without this condition you update all the records with the same account number, not only the records of the "from userid"

Comment: `fr_user_id` parameter is not used in the procedure.

Comment: @bdn02 YES! THANK YOU! It works wonderfully!

Comment: @user4035 yes. I know, but I just simply missed this simple condition on user_id. Thanks for your help!